# Fix or alternative for mktemp in OS X

Tags: shell-script, osx, utilities

I'm looking at a bash script someone else wrote that uses `mktemp`:

```
TEMP=`mktemp --directory`
```

However, this line does not work on my machine (OS X 10.6).

How would I fix this line so that it is cross-un*x-like-platform compatible? **EDIT:** An alternative command would be sufficient as well.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632028/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The following is what I ended up using to reliably create a temporary directory that works on both Linux and Darwin (all versions before Mac OS X 10.11), without hardcoding `$TMPDIR` or `/tmp`:

```
mytmpdir=$(mktemp -d 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d -t 'mytmpdir')
```

---

#### Background:

The GNU mktemp command requires no arguments. Plain `mktemp` will work and  creates a temporary file in the system's temporary directory.

Plain `mktemp -d` will create a directory instead of a file, which is what you'd want to use on Linux.

```
(gnu-coreutils)$ man mktemp
> ..
> If DIR is not specified, uses $TMPDIR if set, else /tmp.
> ..
```

By default, GNU mktemp uses the template `tmp.XXXXXXXXXX` for the name of the sub directory (or file). To customise this template, the `-t` option can be used.

OSX's mktemp has no default template and requires a template to be specified. Unfortunately, where GNU mktemp takes the template as `-t` option, on OSX this is passed as positional argument. Instead, OSX's mktemp has a `-t` option that means something else. The `-t` option on OSX is documented as a "prefix" for the template. It is expanded to `{prefix}.XXXXXXXX`, so it adds the Xs to it automatically (e.g. `mktemp -d -t example` could create `example.zEJZWCTQ` in the temp directory).

I was surprised to find that in many Linux environments, `$TMPDIR` is **not** set by default. Many CLI programs do support it when set, but still need a default for `/tmp`. This means passing `$TMPDIR/example.XXXXXXXX` to mktemp or mkdir is **dangerous**  because it may produce `/example.XXXXXXXX` in the root directory of the local disk (due to $TMPDIR being unset and becoming an empty string).

On OSX, `$TMPDIR` is always set and (at least in the default shell) it is not set to `/tmp` (which is a symlink to `/private/tmp`) but to `/var/folders/dx/*****_*************/T`. So whatever we do for OSX, should honour that default behaviour.

In conclusion, the following is what I ended up using to **reliably create a temporary directory that works on both Linux and Darwin** (Mac OS X), without hardcoding either `$TMPDIR` or `/tmp`:

```
mytmpdir=$(mktemp -d 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d -t 'mytmpdir')
```

The first part is for Linux. This command will fail on Darwin (Mac OS X) with error status code `1` responding with "usage: ...". That's why we ignore stderr and instead then execute the Mac variant. The `mytmpdir` prefix is only used on Mac (where that option is required to be set).

Comment: Really cool. Sometimes OS X different behaviour is annoying.

Comment: @therealmarv I'd rather say, always.

Comment: I just ran `mktemp -d` on OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan, and it worked as expected: `file $(mktemp -d)`: 
`/var/folders/j4/htlnmbf97vlcdszj7_x8g0vh4k3_fp/T/tmp.JXmsrQnL: directory`

Comment: @HeathBorders: that seems to be the first version where that has changed ; on OS X 10.10.5, `mktemp -d` produces a usage message

Comment: Yep. I was surprised as you were that this Just Worked™.

Comment: Also if you run `mktemp -d -t 'mytmpdir'` on Linux (tested with `mktemp` from `coreutils 8.26`), it works as expected.

Comment: @HeathBorders Does Just Worked™ mean there were no unwanted side-effects, or it Just Worked™ meaning it barely passed the threshold of functionality but the wheels are gonna fall off any second now

Comment: I have no idea what `wheels are gonna fall off any second now` means. It could always break between OS X releases, and I haven't tested it on `10.13` `High Sierra` or `10.14` `Mojave`, but I don't think it'll break during a given major version.

Comment: The man page for my OSX (10.14.5 Mojave) says `If no arguments are passed or if only the -d flag is passed mktemp behaves as if -t tmp was supplied.`

Comment: As @D.BenKnoble points out, recent versions of _macOS_ allow `mktemp -d` without the `-t` option. The `-t` option still has different meanings between GNU and macOS (FreeBSD?), but at least both can run `mktemp -d` and produce very similar results... so, the "try GNU-mktemp OR do macOS-mktemp" pattern seems unnecessary.

Comment: OS X 10.11 El Capitan ([shell_cmds-187](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/tree/shell_cmds-187)) was the first release where [`mktemp`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/shell_cmds-187/mktemp/mktemp.c) chose `tmp` as template if no argument was given.

Answer (score 17):

You have to supply a template.  `mktemp -d /tmp/foo.XXXX` should work.  I've never seen `--directory`. The `--` suggests that it is a GNU extension.

Comment: If you want to use `$TMPDIR` when available, do `mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"/foo.XXXX`. That works in bash on the Mac and dash on Debian, so it seems portable.

Comment: @TomAnderson It also works with FreeBSD mktemp(1).

Answer (score 9):

Change `--directory` to `-d`. The former is a GNU-ism, but GNU `mktemp` from coreutils also supports `-d`. The `mktemp` in OS X is the same as from BSD, so `-d` should be pretty portable among systems that actually ship a `mktemp` program.

Comment: I just tried `mktemp -d`, and it does not work either.

Comment: Kyle has the complete answer. The `mktemp` on OS X requires a template. The script you're using assumes GNU conventions, which uses a default template if none is supplied.

Comment: The problem is that unix expects `XXXXX` to be supplied in the template where as OS X does not sure if there is a compatible template flag?

Comment: `mktemp` on OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan works for me: `file $(mktemp -d)`: `/var/folders/j4/htlnmbf97vlcdszj7_x8g0vh4k3_fp/T/tmp.JXmsrQnL: directory`

Answer (score 6):

```
temp_dir="$(mktemp -q -d -t "$(basename "$0").XXXXXX")"
```

- `mktemp` for BSD (including [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mktemp.1.html)) requires a template, but it allows any number of `X`s in the template.
- (GNU) `mktemp` for Linux does not require a template, however, if a template is specified, then the number of `X`s must be 6.

Note that `-t` is deprecated for [GNU `mktemp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html), so a more future-proof code would be

```
temp_dir="$(mktemp -q -d -t "$(basename "$0").XXXXXX" 2>/dev/null || mktemp -q -d)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found to be sure that I create the temporary folder on the `/tmp` directory on both Linux and Mac OS is `mktemp -d '/tmp/mytmpdir.XXXXXX'`

Hope is helpful.