# Is this good in order to have an empty directory?

Tags: bash, directory

I would like to have a directory `mydir` with empty content, but I don't know in advance if it already exists, or when it does, if it is empty. So my way is

```
mkdir -p mydir                                                                                                           
rm -f mydir/*
```

Is there any flaw? What is your better solution?

Comment: If it already exists, should it be cleared out, or fail? What if you don't own it and it's not empty?

Comment: Have you seen http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84980/117549 ?

Comment: @Cyrus how about -rf for any subdirectories of mydir?

Comment: You could use bash constructs too, like `if [ -d mydir ] && [ ! $(ls -A mydir 2>/dev/null) ]; then`...

Comment: I suggest: `rm -rf mydir; mkdir mydir`. @JeffSchaller: I forgot option `-r`.

Comment: That won't delete subdirectories, and won't delete files with names starting with period.

Answer (score 3):

The flaw is that you're using an automated forced removal of a directory—and of course to remove its contents you'd need an automated forced *recursive* removal of a directory.  You're opening yourself up to security holes in your script.

For instance, check out the `--one-file-system` flag for `rm`.  You probably wouldn't want to remove all the files in any filesystems mounted within `mydir`...so you would have to include that flag (which has no abbreviation by the way).

Also, what about bind mounts?  (See `man mount` and search for `bind`.)  Those would be files technically on the same filesystem...how would `rm -rf` handle those?  Would it delete them all?  That's probably not what you wanted, but to be sure you would have to research it out and test the behavior of `rm` in relation to bind mounts.  There are probably many many other edge cases that I didn't think of.

All this trouble comes about because you don't **really** want to "remove a directory and its contents"; what you **actually** want is to *have an empty directory to work in.*

There's a general principle here—when you specify something *other* than what you specifically want, because you think that's a route to get what you want, you are usually introducing needless complexity.  The thing to do is to find how to specify *what you want* and then specify that explicitly.*

---

The better solution, as Jeff Schaller already pointed out in the comments, is to use `mktemp`, which is actually designed for this purpose.  Specifically, from `man mktemp`:

```
Create a temporary file or directory, safely, and print its name.
```

The simplest use of `mktemp` to create a directory would look like this:

```
mydir="$(mktemp -d)"
```

Then you could copy a file into it like so:

```
cp somefile "$mydir/"
```

At the end of your script, when you're all done with the directory, you can *safely* remove it (and whatever you've put in it) by using:

```
rm -rf "$mydir"
```

---

<sub>*Another example of this principle is the use of `sed` commands to handle field-based or column-based files.  You may be able to do it...but you can specify *exactly* what you want by using `awk`, and with much less complexity.</sub>

Comment: w/ `sed` you can do it faster, more specifically, and more flexibly. coming from one who has never understood `awk`, i would also argue your *complexity* statement - regexp is *very* basic. but it is also actually a mathematical equation. i dunno if you can get more exact than that.

Comment: @mikeserv, it's actually funny to me that you claim that `sed` is "more flexible" but in the same breath admit to never having understood `awk`.  That's like saying that machine code is "more flexible" than Perl or Lisp (without learning either), because "Perl and Lisp have to be turned into machine code anyways before they are executed by the CPU."  `awk` was **designed** to handle field-based data and it is *excellent* for that purpose.

Comment: but that's what regular expressions do - they define matched fields. And anyway, I breathed *twice*. And yeah, I don't understand `awk` - it's way too complicated. I like *simple* expressions - I like to *balance equations*. Regular expressions work that way inherently with *primitives* that build and compound. That's *simple*. `awk` is a gigantic scripting language - it abstracted and confounded every which way. It is far from *simple*. `sed` is more flexible in that it gives you a direct interface to the system's regex libs. *You* call the shots, not the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

`mkdir` fails because it should. That's a good thing. A failing command is a command that is *working*. It's correctly returning to you a testable error code. And so the simple thing to do is test it.

```
:& cd -P "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}" || exit
x=$(((z=($$+$!)/2+1000)-1001))
until mkdir -m a=,u=rwx "work.$0.$((x+=1))" &&
      cd -- "work.$0.$x"
do    [ "$x" -lt "$z" ]    || ! break
done  2>/dev/null          &&
WORK=$PWD exec 9<.
```

Comment: -1 because this is **not** the "simple thing to do."  I pray I never have to maintain code written like this.

Comment: @Wildcard - written like what? It's a group of 7 self-evident lines that either obtains a secure temporary working directory and returns true or it doesn't and returns false. What do you think it does?

Comment: "...7 **self-evident** lines..."—If I hadn't read so many of your answers, I would think that this was trolling.  But I do think you honestly believe it.  There's no point in discussing it with you when you're so set in your ways.  I'll just say this: `mydir="$(mktemp -d)"` could be explained to a kid in grade school in about 30 seconds.  Your "self-evident" code requires *vast* knowledge in *excruciating* detail about the inner workings of the shell before it's even possible to *guess* what it does, let alone prove its correctness.  Code clarity and code maintainability **does have value**.

Comment: @Wildcard - it says: `cd tmpdir || exit; until mkdir && cd work; do x -lt z || ! break; done && work=$pwd`. It doesn't involve piped data or prngs. There is no inherent difficulty with specific unix systems, or failure to find a command. Can you explain those things to the third grader? In my opinion, that's stuff he ought to know.